# Problem of can't publish the Web API in IIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, webapi

[This is the error that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbA8k.png)

Can anyone tell me what problem is this?

```
</configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="StudentDetailsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/StudentDataModel.csdl|res://*/StudentDataModel.ssdl|res://*/StudentDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=LAPTOP-JQRLR1PP\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=StudentDetails;User=sa;Password=xxx;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
      <add name="StudentDetailsEntities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/StudentDataModel.csdl|res://*/StudentDataModel.ssdl|res://*/StudentDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=LAPTOP-JQRLR1PP\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=StudentDetails;User=sa;Password=xxx;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: You EntityFramework code (it is the API that handles the database) is giving an error. The InnerException has the details. It is not connecting to the database, could be a database problem (wrong login) or an application configuration problem.

Comment: It seems that you have some problem connecting to the database set in the configuration of your application. Is the database available from the publishing site?

Comment: @Cleptus What I need to check?

Comment: @Steve No, but the web API can run out.

Comment: The WEB API can run but during publishing the Web API getting these error.

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to help you. Please edit it and provide information on what database is (sql server, mysql, oracle, etc) and the connection string used. Usually changing from windows authentication to database login (database managed user/password) works

Comment: I am using SQL server database

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2):

The `Integrated Security=True` is incompatible with `User=xxx;Password=yyy`

Depending on your specific scenario it should be either:

```
initial catalog=StudentDetails;integrated security=True;
```

or

```
initial catalog=StudentDetails;User=sa;Password=xxxx;
```

The first one would use the credentials of the user running the process, the second one the database user 'sa'.

As long as you already know good working credentials (the 'sa' user) I would suggest the second option.

Comment: Using only the user/password option gives you that error? @venus. Try the second option, it is probable that your laptop user has no login crated in the sql server database.